# Port 80 being used by Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

Tags: windows, iis-7, port, netstat

It's been quite a few days that port is being used by some strange process which i don't know
 Initially i thought it's related to SQL Server. I tried stopping all the services which starts from SQL :). 
 But it's still the same. To determine the problem i even ran cports.
[error](http://i42.tinypic.com/124wjl4.jpg)
This is strange!

I'm not running any other service which use port 80 (Teamviewer or Skype).

This is what i got when ran **netsh http show urlacl**

```
URL Reservations: 
----------------- 

Reserved URL            : http://*:2869/ 
    User: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;LS) 

Reserved URL            : http://+:80/Temporary_Listen_Addresses/ 
    User: \Everyone
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD) 

Reserved URL            : http://+:80/116B50EB-ECE2-41ac-8429-9F9E963361B7/ 
    User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;NS) 

Reserved URL            : https://+:443/C574AC30-5794-4AEE-B1BB-6651C5315029/ 
    User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;NS) 

Reserved URL            : http://+:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/ 
    User: NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;IU) 

Reserved URL            : http://*:5357/ 
    User: BUILTIN\Users
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
    User: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;BU)(A;;GX;;;LS) 

Reserved URL            : https://*:5358/ 
    User: BUILTIN\Users
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
    User: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;BU)(A;;GX;;;LS) 

Reserved URL            : http://+:47001/wsman/ 
    User: NT SERVICE\WinRM
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
    User: NT SERVICE\Wecsvc
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-80-569256582-2953403351-2909559716-1301513147-412116970)(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-80-4059739203-877974739-1245631912-527174227-2996563517) 

Reserved URL            : http://+:5985/wsman/ 
    User: NT SERVICE\WinRM
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
    User: NT SERVICE\Wecsvc
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-80-569256582-2953403351-2909559716-1301513147-412116970)(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-80-4059739203-877974739-1245631912-527174227-2996563517) 

Reserved URL            : https://+:5986/wsman/ 
    User: NT SERVICE\WinRM
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
    User: NT SERVICE\Wecsvc
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-80-569256582-2953403351-2909559716-1301513147-412116970)(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-80-4059739203-877974739-1245631912-527174227-2996563517) 

Reserved URL            : https://+:443/sra_{BA195980-CD49-458b-9E23-C84EE0ADCD75}/ 
    User: NT SERVICE\SstpSvc
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: Yes
    User: BUILTIN\Administrators
        Listen: No
        Delegate: No
    User: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: Yes
        SDDL: D:(A;;GA;;;S-1-5-80-3435701886-799518250-3791383489-3228296122-2938884314)(A;;GR;;;BA)(A;;GA;;;SY) 

Reserved URL            : http://+:10243/WMPNSSv4/ 
    User: NT SERVICE\WMPNetworkSvc
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-80-2375682873-768044350-3534595160-1005545032-2873800392) 

Reserved URL            : https://+:10245/WMPNSSv4/ 
    User: NT SERVICE\WMPNetworkSvc
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;S-1-5-80-2375682873-768044350-3534595160-1005545032-2873800392) 

Reserved URL            : http://127.0.0.1:47873/help/ 
    User: \Everyone
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD) 

Reserved URL            : http://+:80/MSDEPLOYAGENTSERVICE/ 
    User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;NS) 

Reserved URL            : http://dualpower7:80/ 
    User: \Everyone
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD) 

Reserved URL            : https://dualpower7:443/ 
    User: \Everyone
        Listen: Yes
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;;GX;;;WD) 

Reserved URL            : http://+:10243/ZuneNSSv1/ 
    User: NT SERVICE\ZuneNetworkSvc
        Listen: No
        Delegate: No
        SDDL: D:(A;OICI;KA;;;S-1-5-80-1579159853-1092138755-2075097677-1891485308-398811743)
```

So what could be the cause?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run the following command at a command prompt: `NETSH HTTP SH SER`

That will list the process bindings for each queue / port / namespace. `URLACL` isn't quite the same.

Comment: here you go http://pastebin.com/XXv9NjpS it looks like its related to IIS. what you say?

Comment: Port 80 looks like it's registered for MSDeployAgentService. Maybe uninstall the web deployment tool or MS Web Deployment Tool, however it appears in Add/Remove Programs.

Comment: Done some other crazy and goofy stuff which actually stopped MS Web Deployment eventually. Thanks for the help mate :)